# Passing an instance variable from a model to a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello (hopefully) omniscient Rails folks ;)

I'm currently trying to generate a set of radio buttons from an instance variable in one of my models. Because the MVC pattern prohibits passing data from models directly into the views, I somehow have to include the controller as kind of a middleman. The problem is that I can't access the instance variable of my model even though I use 'attr_reader :valid_statuses'. Therefore it's also not possible to pass the data down to my view...

This is how my user model looks like at the moment. The '@valid_statuses' array contains the strings which should be used to generate the radio buttons.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_reader :valid_statuses
  @valid_statuses = %w(new editor admin blocked)
  validates :status, inclusion: { in: @valid_statuses }
end
```

The controller looks like this. @user is not nil, but @valid_statuses is

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @valid_statuses = @user.valid_statuses
  end
  ...
end
```

The _form.html.erb:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :status %>
  <% @valid_statuses.each do |item| %>
    <%= f.radio_button :status, item %> <%= item %><br />
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I would be very greateful if someone knows the answer to this and could share it with me and the rest of the world! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case, you have to use constants (if you wanna only fix your code):

model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  VALID_STATUSES = %w(new editor admin blocked)
  validates :status, inclusion: { in: VALID_STATUSES }
end
```

controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  ...
end
```

view:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :status %>
  <% User::VALID_STATUSES.each do |item| %>
    <%= f.radio_button :status, item %> <%= item %><br />
  <% end %>
</div>
```

BUT I better use `enum` with name `status`:

model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: [:new, :editor, :admin, :blocked]
end
```

[READ NORE ABOUT ENUMs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I'll have a look into the enums!

Comment: @krebas yep, good choice. `enum`s have many profits and syntax sugar

Answer (score 1):

Valid statuses don't change from one User to another.

So you define `@valid_statuses` inside the class User. `@valid_statuses` isn't defined for a specific `@user`, but for the whole class. `attr_reader :valid_statuses` tries to find the instance variable `@valid_statuses` of `@user`, which hasn't been defined.

Here's a possible modification :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  @valid_statuses = %w(new editor admin blocked)
  validates :status, inclusion: { in: @valid_statuses }
  def self.valid_statuses
    @valid_statuses
  end
end
```

and in your views :

```
User.valid_statuses
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a class instance variable rather than a class variable -so `@valid_statuses` rather than `@@valid_statuses`